# I need to determine the domain of convergence and whether the series converge uniformly.

Tags: uniform-convergence

Here is the series: $\Sigma^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{4n}} $

Here is what I did:
Given that  $1+x^{4n} > x^{4n}$ we use the series $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{x^{2n}}{x^{4n}} = \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{1}{x^{2n}}$, then for $|x| \ge 1 \ \ \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{1}{x^{2n}} \in R \Rightarrow \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{4n}} \in R$

But in the feedback of this exercise, I was told that I haven't found the domain of convergence. From the previously given proof one can conclude that the domain of the convergence is $x \in (-\infty, -1] \cup [1, +\infty)$ or is it not correct? Furthermore, how can I test for uniform convergence within the domain of $[\ln3, + \infty)$?
Ok, one poster gave a hint, that I need to determine the convergence domain for $\frac{1}{x^{2n}}$. So, in order for the series to convergence, I need that$-1< \frac{1}{x} < 1 $ (I think, I can take the geometric series power to be $2n$, correct?). Then for that to happen $|x|>1$. So, the domain of convergence for these geometric series is $(-\infty,-1[ \cup ]1,\infty)$. But I guess I cannot conclude that the domain of convergence for $\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{4n}}$ is the same, but how then I determine it?

Comment: You seem to have used the geometric series. What's its domain of convergence?

Comment: @Divide1918 For the geometric series it would be $\forall x |x|>1$. But I don't know how from there conclude the convergence domain for the original series, nevermind the uniformity of convergence.

Comment: The series fails to converge for $|x|=1$.

Comment: @MarkViola Why? And how from there the domain of convergence is derived?

Comment: Seriously?  If $x=\pm 1$, then $\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{4n}}=\frac12$ for all $n$.